# Pass parent's attributes to child component with children method

Tags: reactjs

I have a situation like that:

I call parent modal component with content:

```
<Modal onClickOnYesButton ={() => console.log('test')}>
   <ModalContent />
</Modal>
```

Modal component itself looks like that:

```
const Modal = ({ children }) => {
  return(
   <div>
    {children}
   </div>
  )
}
```

So modal content component is rendered inside the modal using `children`.
The question is how could I pass `onClickOnYesButton` to `<ModalContent />` without placing it directly as a ModalContent attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how could I pass onClickOnYesButton to  without
>   placing it directly as a ModalContent attribute

If you want to pass props down to the child you can use `React.cloneElement(children, { ...props })` inside of your `Modal`.

i.e. something like this:

```
const Modal = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  return(
   <div>
    { React.cloneElement(children, { ...props }) }
   </div>
  )
}
```

Though note that this will only work for a single child, if you have more then you will need to wrap `React.cloneElement` within `React.Children.map`.

Answer (score 0):

Can define the method used in onClick as a static method and import the component and access the function with `<ComponentName>.<functionName>`.

```js
class ModalParent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Modal>
        <ModalContents />
      </Modal>
    );
  }
  static onClickYes = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target, 'yes')
  }
}

class ModalContents extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={ModalParent.onClickYes}>Some Modal Contents</div>
    );
  }
}

class Modal extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="modal" onClick={ModalParent.onClickYes}>
        <h1>Modal</h1>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ModalParent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.modal {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Your solution is passing it as an attribute: `<ModalContents onClick={this.onClickYes} />`, which is what the question is **not** wanting to do.

Comment: Static method option was added, I'll swap out the code